# How to find out what cause cmake function does not work?

Tags: function, cmake

I want to move some cmake command to a funtion .   But the command did not work in the function.
I test a file command and it works well directly in the CMakeLists.txt but not in the function abcde.
So what's wrong with the function?

```
function(abcde)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES src4/*.cpp)
endfunction()

# file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES src4/*.cpp) 
abcde()
```

Weird is that the function works well in the past few days and suddenly did not work. And my function has a few commands, some work and others don't work.

I use vs code and it's cmake tools extension.

Comment: A function adds a **scope**. So `SOURCE_FILES` variable is set inside the function but not outside it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks very mush, that'a the problem.   But why it worked well in the past few days,which make me confused.